# How to generate random numbers which do not include zeros?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, random, integer

I am trying to create a program which finds [multiplicative persistence](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultiplicativePersistence.html) in numbers which are randomized. This program, however, has to deal with large numbers (>10<sup>233</sup>). However, when I use `random.randint(10**233, 10**400)`, I cannot help but notice that the vast majority of numbers contain a zero, which would result in 0 multiplicative persistence. In my algorithm, I am attempting to get rid of these numbers with the following approach:

```py
def find_new_i():
    i = 10
    while "0" in str(i):
        i = random.randint(10**233,10**400)
    return i
```

However, this approach is really slow, and cannot generate numbers very quickly.

Has anyone got any ideas on a more efficient approach?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly generating numbers that doesn't contain any zeroes (by e.g. assembling a string of digits 1-9) rather than simply generating all values and throwing away the "vast majority" of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The odds to have a 0 in such a big number are very high, which is why the `while` loop is likely to repeat itself many times.

You are better of replacing any zeros with a random digit between 1 and 9.

```
def find_new_i():
    i = random.randint(10 ** 233, 10 ** 400)
    i = int(''.join(str(random.randint(1, 9)) if d == '0' else d for d in str(i)))
    return i
```

or if you don't mind all the zeros being replaced with the same random digit:

```
i = int(str(i).replace('0', str(random.randint(1, 9))))
```

At this stage it might make more sense to simply build the number "manually" (however this approach is about 4 times slower than the above, see the comments):

```
def find_new_i():
    return int(''.join(str(random.randint(1, 9))
               for _ in range(random.randint(233, 400))))
```

Comment: 10% of the digits will be zero in any long, randomly genterated. number — not sure I'd call the "very high".

Comment: @martineau the odds of *even one* zero digit in a 233-400 digit number is practically 100%.  Compute `1-0.9**233` for example.

Comment: @martineau - 10% of the digits are zero, so the chance that the entire number contains at least one zero is 1 - 0.9**n, which grows very high with that many digits.

Comment: Your first `find_new_i` is about four times faster than the "manual" one.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Interesting. I didn't bother checking the performance differences. I wonder why though. They both end up building 233-400 chars-long strings. I don't have the time to profile now, but maybe calling `random.randint` 233-400 times is what accounts for the overhead

Comment: Using `random.choice('123456789')` ends up twice as fast compared to using `str(random.randint(1, 9))`, but that puts it at half as fast as the original. I'm guessing the original is fastest because it only has to call a function to generate a random value for 10% of the digits rather than all of them (and `random.randint(10 ** 233, 10 ** 400)` on its own is negligible).

Comment: This is a about 20% faster than the first one: `int(''.join(choices('123456789',k=randint(233,400))))`

Comment: @MarkTolonen.  Small problem with your solution.  The odds of getting a 233-digit result in your solution is 1/177, while in the original problem as stated, it should be infinitesimal.  You do not have a random distribution in which all results are equally likely.

Comment: @DeepSpace.  My previous comment also applies to your second solution.  Picking a random number between 233 and 400, and then generating a random number with that many digits does not give you the same distribution as what as expected.  In a correct solution, ~90% of the results should be the longest possible length.    First solution is fine.

Comment: @FrankYellin True, that's actually an issue with the last solution in this answer as well.

Comment: @MarkTolonen.  Hmm.  We both noticed the same thing as the same time!

Comment: Picking a random number and getting the digit length makes the solution only 3% faster:    `i = randint(10 ** 233, 10 ** 400 - 1); n = floor(log(i)/log(10)); int(''.join(choices('123456789',k=n)))`.  I added the `-1` because randint could just exactly one 400-digit number, but choices would generate *many* more.  I was hoping eliminating so many int->str conversions would help...but the math slows it back down again.